# Cause-and-effect questions about growth and development of plant

Tags: botany, homework, development, growth

I need to solve some cause-and-effect problems. The problems are related to growth and development of plant. "Growth and Development" chapter is the first chapter in third level of high school (senior high school).

**Show your answer with "Is the statement true?", "Is the reason true?" and "Are the statement and reason have cause-and-effect relationship?"**

Problem 1

> *Anthurium* should be sprayed with cytokinin hormone to prevent from wither easily.
>
> **Reason**
>
> Cytokinin hormone promotes/stimulates the growth of axillary buds that will **produce lateral branching**.

Problem 2

> The stem of *Avena sativa* with the coleoptile is being cut, couldn't elongate.
>
> **Reason**
>
> Phytohormone that used for growing is only available at the end/peak of coleoptile.

My attempts to those problems are here:

**Problem 1**

What I know about cytokinin is when you soak the green leaves in the water with cytokinin, the green color will stay longer than without any soaking. I don't have any idea about the effect of cytokinin to flowers. I think I need to dig more knowledge about the hormone.
I'm not sure with the reason too. Quick searching in Google *Cytokinin* and Wikipedia gives this:

> ... This promotes shoot growth, and restricts lateral branching.

The problem is my textbook clearly said that **the cytokinin promotes the producing of lateral branching**.

Because I couldn't prove the statement and reason, I couldn't give their relationship.

**Problem 2**

I think even the coleoptile is being cut, the flower must not easy to die. The phytohormone must be related with auxine hormone or other thing.

Because I couldn't prove the statement and reason, I couldn't give their relationship.

Any idea or answer is appreciated!

*Feel free to edit my grammar. English is not my native language, but I could understand your post in English.*